# Running Oracle stored procs from C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ora-06550

A beginner question: 
I have a stored proc (just a procedure, without any packages) in the Oracle Database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure FII_DBO.CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT
IS
BEGIN
 ...
END CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT;
```

and it works fine in TOAD. However, when I try to run it from C# it complains:

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

relevant C# code:

```
Command = new OracleCommand();
Command.CommandText = procedureName;
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Command.Connection = connection;
Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the Oracle user that your .NET application is connecting with has permissions to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: @Ian Nelson, @Grzenio - I have a similar issue. The same error and the C# code looks much the same except I am using `ExecuteReader()`. I don't see how it could be permissions as the User ID I am connecting with is the owner of the schema and the specific procedures too. Any other reasons this might occur?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, the error message was a bit misleading. I was executing it as a different user, who didn't have the proper access rights. This did the trick:

```
grant execute on FII_DBO.CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT to FII_USER;
```

Comment: Yeah, the error message is less than helpful, but I guess the thinking is that it's done for security purposes. If the user can't access the stored procedure, then the database won't even admit to its existence.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the package name in the procedureName variable?

i.e. setting procedureName to "`FII_DBO.CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT`", not just "`CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT`"?

Comment: Yeah, tried that as well: identifier 'FII_DBO.CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT' must be declared

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure seems to be created in another schema.

Issue

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = FII_DBO
```

right after connecting.

I recall the provider has some bugs with calling stored procedures.

Set your `CommandText` to

```
BEGIN FII_DBO.CLEAR_UNIT_TEST_PRODUCT(); END;
```

and `CommandType` to `Text`

Also you may try to change the case of you stored procedure name, like:

```
fii_dbo.clear_unit_test_product
```

, I recall that the case matters too.